# How to make a CAF not a CAF in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, compiler-optimization

How do I make a Constant Applicative Form into, well, not a Constant Applicative Form, to stop it being retained for the lifetime of the program?

I've tried this approach:

```
-- | Dummy parameter to avoid creating a CAF
twoTrues :: () -> [[[Bool]]]
twoTrues _ = map (++ (True : repeat False)) . trueBlock <$> [1..]
```

but it doesn't seem to work - the profile shows it as still being retained *and* still marks it as a CAF.

I've found one relevant Google result on this, [a reply by Simon Peyton-Jones](http://www.mail-archive.com/glasgow-haskell-users@haskell.org/msg12102.html) to Neil Mitchell who asked precisely this question - but that answer refers to a dead link, unfortunately.

Comment: In case it's useful, the message that the dead link was referring to can be found [here](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2007-April/012379.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Generalise.** If you have a constant value, can you generalise this to a function of some variable? The naming of my function in the question, `twoTrues`, immediately suggests that this constant is the third in a sequence `zeroTrues`, `oneTrue`, `twoTrues`, `threeTrues` etc. - and indeed it is. So generalising `twoTrues` into a function `nTrues` *which takes a parameter n* and deleting `twoTrues`, would eliminate one CAF from the program.

As it happens, in this case, I had only considered the cases `zeroTrues`, `oneTrue` and `twoTrues` for my program because that was all I needed, but my program could naturally be extended to deal with `nTrues` for `n` > 2 - so generalising to `nTrues` would mean it would make sense to "generalise all the way up" to the users of `zeroTrues`, `oneTrue` etc. That would not always be the case.

Note: there might still be other CAFs to deal with, either in the code, or produced by GHC's "optimisations" (which are not really optimisations in these pathological cases).

This answer may involve more work by the programmer than is strictly necessary, however. It isn't actually necessary to generalise, as Don's answer shows.

On the other hand, in some cases, generalising a constant can make it more clear what you are actually doing, and aid reusability. It can even reveal ways to compute a series of values in a better systematic way, and/or more efficiently.

A note about this particular case (which can be ignored): In this particular case, I would not want to make `nTrues` *itself* into an infinite list (which would be a CAF again, reintroducing the original problem!) rather than a function. One reason is that while `twoTrues` could be useful in the form of an infinite list, I can't see how it would be useful (in my application, anyway) for `nTrues` to be in the form of an infinite list.

Answer (score 16):

**A complete example**

Here's a little example that shows the situation:

```
module A where

big :: () -> [Int]
big _ = [1..10^7]
```

Looks like a function, right? But what does GHC do? It floats the enum to the top level!

```
A.big1 :: [Int]
[ Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=False,
         ConLike=False, Cheap=False, Expandable=False,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 7 0}]
A.big1 =
  case A.$wf1 10 A.big2 of ww_sDD { __DEFAULT ->
  eftInt 1 ww_sDD
  }

A.big :: () -> [Int]
[Arity=1,    
 Unf=Unf{Src=InlineStable, TopLvl=True, Arity=1, Value=True,
         ConLike=True, Cheap=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=True)
         Tmpl= \ _ -> A.big1}]
A.big = \ _ -> A.big1
```

Ooops!

---

So what can we do?

**Turn off optimizations**

That works, `-Onot`, but not desirable:

```
A.big :: () -> [Int]
[GblId, Arity=1]
A.big =
  \ _ ->
    enumFromTo
      @ Int
      $fEnumInt
      (I# 1)
      (^
         @ Int
         @ Type.Integer
         $fNumInt
         $fIntegralInteger
         (I# 10)
         (smallInteger 7))
```

**Don't inline, and more functons**

Make *everything* into a function, including the `enumFromTo`, plumbing the parameter through to the workers:

```
big :: () -> [Int]
big u = myEnumFromTo u 1 (10^7)
{-# NOINLINE big #-}

myEnumFromTo :: () -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
myEnumFromTo _ n m = enumFromTo n m
{-# NOINLINE myEnumFromTo #-}
```

Now we are finally CAF-free! Even with `-O2`

```
A.myEnumFromTo [InlPrag=NOINLINE]
  :: () -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
A.myEnumFromTo =
  \ _ (n_afx :: Int) (m_afy :: Int) ->
    $fEnumInt_$cenumFromTo n_afx m_afy

A.big [InlPrag=NOINLINE] :: () -> [Int]
A.big = \ (u_abx :: ()) -> A.myEnumFromTo u_abx A.$s^2 lvl3_rEe
```

Yay.

---

What doesn't work?

*Turn off -ffull-laziness*

The full laziness transformation floats definitions outwards. It is on by default with `-O1` or above. Let's try turning it off with `-fno-full-laziness`. However, it doesn't work.

Comment: How am I supposed to _use_ `big ()`?  If I write `main = do { print $ length $ big (); print $ length $ big () }`, the common subexpression elimination is applied to the expression `big ()` and it is floated to the top level (according to the core produced by GHC 7.0.3), and the program requires a lot of space, invalidating the whole effort to avoid sharing made in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be a long-standing problem http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/917 . And in my opinion a critical one.

Comment: It's an open research question, however.

Comment: It is sad that we have to fight the optimizer and do trial-and-error (modify a code, compile, see the core, repeat until you get a desired core) to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Don Stewart is there any open discussion about this question? I'd like to see any proposals, arguments and counterarguments. May be interesting.

Comment: @ivanvadovič In theory, the compiler have the right to conclude that since `()` does not contain anything, it can be optimised out. So the idea is to avoid `()` as a parameter since they can always be eliminated. Instead, whenever you want to use `()` as a parameter, replace it with an unused type variable.

Answer (score 5):

With the introduction of a dummy parameter, you also have to make it look like the result actually depends on the parameter. Otherwise, GHC's cleverness might turn it into a CAF again.

I suggest the following:

```
twoTrues u = map (++ (True : repeat False)) . trueBlock <$> [(u `seq` 1)..]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to hide the fact that the rhs is a CAF from the optimizer.
Something like this should do it.

```
twoTrues :: () -> [[[Bool]]]
twoTrues u = map (++ (True : repeat (false u))) . trueBlock <$> [1..]

{-# NOINLINE false #-}
false :: () -> Bool
false _ = False
```

Comment: I think the `[1..]` will be floated to the top level no matter what though.

Comment: Ah, yes.  You need to hide that one too.  Some more obfuscated code should do. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible solution might be to tell the compiler to inline it. (Note: this answer is untested. If it doesn't work, please comment below.)

Even if (hypothetically) the compiler refuses to inline it for some reason, you can use `cpp` instead, by #defining it:

```
#define twoTrues (map (++ (True : repeat False)) . trueBlock <$> [1..])
```

(although with that approach, of course, *it won't appear in the module's interface*, so you can only use it within that module).

The `-cpp` option tells GHC to preprocess the input file with cpp.

Inlining would mean duplicating the code *n* times if you refer to `twoTrues` in *n>1* places. However, while that's theoretically undesirable, it's probably not going to be a significant problem in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `()` as a parameter, what you are going to say is actually

> Although I have declared a parameter here, I am not interesting in what it is and I am not going to do anything with its value.

You are not interesting in it, because `()` does not have anything interesting at all; you are not going to do anything with it, because you can do nothing with `()`.

The problem of it is that the compiler have the right to optimise it out since there is only one possible value to pass so its use is always predictable and so why not assume it? But it moves it back to CAF and makes the idea does not work.

Fortunately, there is another way to do so. Look at the following modification of `twoTrues`:

```
twoTrues :: a -> [[[Bool]]]
twoTrues _ = map (++ (True : repeat False)) . trueBlock <$> [1..]
```

Now you can use `twoTrues` like this:

```
map concat $ twoTrues()
```

Since `a` is an unused type parameter, the caller can pass anything. And because you don't know what it would be so you have no idea what you can do with it. This is actually forcing you to ignore its value. So it is basically declaring the same statement I mentioned before.

Of cause, you can now pass any thing (including `undefined`) to that function. But it does not matter and actually it is this possibility makes this trick workable, since the compiler can no longer predict how this function being used. When the human user sees this function they should know what you are going to say here and conclude passing `()` is the easiest, but even if they don't and passing something else, it would not break anything and since Haskell is lazy the additional parameter could never be evaluated at all.

So what if `()` being used as a result? This is even worse. Since returning `()` means your function do not do anything at all (in Haskell, all effects of a function shall represented in its return value), the compiler have the right to conclude your function is not necessary.

The conclusion is, `()` as a type shall not appear in type signatures unless used with some other type (i.e. in `IO ()`).

**EDIT**

Now one may wonder, if there is only one way to implement `a -> String` from a `String`, why the compiler cannot conclude they are the same. The answer turn out to be that you actually have two way to implement this.

```
usual :: a -> String
usual _ = "Hello World!"

unusual :: a -> String
unusual a = seq a "Hello World!"
```

For almost all input, `usual value = unusual value`, but `usual undefined` is `"Hello World!"` whilst `unusual undefined` is `undefined`.

In a human point of view, `unusual` is pretty unusual, because it forces to evaluate a value unrelated to the final result. If in any case you do need such a thing, simply call `seq` would be easier. Furthermore, since Haskell is by default lazy, if you want to define a function that is strict, you'd better document this behavior. So if you see such a signature without additional documentation you have the right to assume it is implemented in the `usual` way.

Comment: This sounds off. Humans reason about `()` like that; GHC does not. Note that a function can choose to `seq` a value of type `()` as well, and potentially get exceptions.