# Create a new expression without pointer from previous one

Tags: haskell

I am reading the book https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/haskell-high-performance-programming and trying to figure out, what is the difference between those two functions:

This functions does memoize the intermediate numbers:

```
fib_mem :: Int -> Integer
fib_mem = (map fib [0..] !!)
            where fib 0 = 1
                  fib 1 = 1
                  fib n = fib_mem (n-2) + fib_mem (n-1)
```

and this not:

```
fib_mem_arg :: Int -> Integer
fib_mem_arg x = map fib [0..] !! x
                where fib 0 = 1
                      fib 1 = 1
                      fib n = fib_mem_arg (n-2) + fib_mem_arg (n-1)
```

The author tries to explain as following:

> Running fib_mem_arg with anything but very small arguments, one can
>   confirm it does no memoization. Even though we can see that map fib
>   [0..] does not depend on the argument number and could be memorized,
>   it will not be, **because applying an argument to a function will create
>   a new expression that cannot implicitly have pointers to expressions
>   from previous function applications**.

What does he mean with the sentence, that is bold marked? Could someone provide me a simple example?

Why `fib_mem` is a `constant applicative form`?

Comment: But the bold sentence is wrong! After all, `fib_mem 30000` and `fib_mem 30001` are applications of functions to arguments, but the latter implicitly has pointers to the former and so whichever one you do first takes *significantly* longer. They're pointing their blaming finger at the wrong problem!

Comment: See also: [What are constant applicative forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8330756/791604).

Comment: @DanielWagner Maybe a simple example would be not bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why `fib_mem` is a *constant applicative form*?

Not `fib_mem`, but `(map fib [0..] !!)`. It is a [CAF](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form) because it is a partially applied function `(!!)`. As such it is subject to memory retention.

(see also: [What are super combinators and constant applicative forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8330756/791604))

Since the type is monomorphic, it is retained in memory even between calls to `fib_mem`, in effect as if having `map fib [0..]` "floated" to the top level, as if defined as

```
fib_mem_m :: Int -> Integer
fib_mem_m = (the_list !!)
            where fib 0 = 1
                  fib 1 = 1
                  fib n = (the_list !! (n-2)) + (the_list !! (n-1))
the_list = map fib [0..]
```

If the type were polymorphic, the floating to top level wouldn't be possible, but it would still be retained for the duration of each call to `fib_mem`, as if defined as

```
fib_mem_p :: Num a => Int -> a
fib_mem_p = (the_list !!)
            where fib 0 = 1
                  fib 1 = 1
                  fib n = (the_list !! (n-2)) + (the_list !! (n-1))
                  the_list = map fib [0..]
```

To see the difference, evaluate `fib_mem_m 10000` twice, at the GHCi propt. The second attempt will take 0 seconds. But `fib_mem_p 10000` will take same amount of time each time it is called. It will still be as fast as the first one, so there is still memoization going on there, it's just not retained between calls.

With this style of definition, the full application as in `fib_mem_arg` will too be memoized -- and just as the one above, not between the calls to `fib_mem_arg`, but only during each call.

```
fib_mem_arg :: Num a => Int -> Integer  -- or polymorphic, makes no difference
fib_mem_arg x = the_list !! x
            where fib 0 = 1
                  fib 1 = 1
                  fib n = (the_list !! (n-2)) + (the_list !! (n-1))
                  the_list = map fib [0..]
```

Comment: Why this is a CAF `z = (+) 4` and this not `z = \x -> 4 + x`? What is the different?

Comment: by definition, lambda expression is not a CAF. that's what the wiki page is saying.

Comment: Super combinators look like for me functions composition, for instance `h(g (f x) )`. Is it right?

Comment: and why `z n = [1..n]` is not CAF? `n` is a bound variable.

Comment: `h(g (f x) )` is an expression with  a lot of free variables. You need to show the left hand side of the equation (definition). ---- in `z n = [1..n]` the `n` on the RHS depends on `n` on the LHS, thus `z` is not CAF. indeed it can be called as `z 5` first, and then `z 3`. these will be two different values, not one.

Comment: `z n = [1..n]` is a lambda abstration?

Comment: it is equivalent to `z = \n -> [1..n]`, yes. Not *eta*-equivalent like `((+) 4) =~= (\x -> ((+) 4) x) = (\x -> 4 + x)`, but *directly* equivalent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188733/discussion-between-will-ness-and-zero-coding).