# Avoiding CAF in Haskell

Tags: haskell, optimization, caf, strictness

To avoid CAF (resource sharing), I tried converting to function
with dummy argument, but no success (`noCafB`). 
I've read [How to make a CAF not a CAF in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090932/how-to-make-a-caf-not-a-caf-in-haskell) so tried `noCafC` and `noCafD`. When compiled with
`-O0`, then functions with dummy argument did evaluated every time.
However, with `-O2`, it seems that GHC converts those functions to
CAF. Is this intended behaviour (GHC's optimization)?

```
module Main where
import Debug.Trace

cafA :: [Integer]
cafA = trace "hi" (map (+1) $ [1..])
noCafB :: a -> [Integer]
noCafB _ = trace "hi" (map (+1) $ [1..])
noCafC :: a -> [Integer]
noCafC _ = trace "hi" (map (+1) $ [1..])
{-# NOINLINE noCafC #-}
noCafD :: a -> [Integer]
noCafD _ = trace "hi" (map (+1) $ myEnumFrom 0 1)
{-# NOINLINE noCafD #-}
myEnumFrom :: a -> Integer -> [Integer]
myEnumFrom _ n =  enumFrom n
{-# NOINLINE myEnumFrom #-}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "cafA"
  print $ (cafA !! 1 + cafA !! 2)
  putStrLn "noCafB"
  print $ (noCafB 0 !! 1 + noCafB 0 !! 2)
  putStrLn "noCafC"
  print $ (noCafC 0 !! 1 + noCafC 0 !! 2)
  putStrLn "noCafD"
  print $ (noCafD 0 !! 1 + noCafD 0 !! 2)
```

Result with `-O2`

```
$ stack ghc -- --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3

$ stack ghc -- -O2 cafTest.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( cafTest.hs, cafTest.o )
Linking cafTest ...
$ ./cafTest
cafA
hi
7
noCafB
7
noCafC
7
noCafD
hi
7
```

Result with `-O0`

```
$ stack ghc -- -O0 cafTest.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( cafTest.hs, cafTest.o )
Linking cafTest ...
$ ./cafTest
cafA
hi
7
noCafB
hi
hi
7
noCafC
hi
hi
7
noCafD
hi
hi
7
```

I've also tried without `trace` but results was same. under `-O2`, I found that the result of `incInt` function is shared by inspecting profiling output. Why this behaviour?

```
incIntOrg :: [Integer]
incInt = map (+1) [1..]

incInt :: a -> [Integer]  -- results IS shared. should it be?
incInt _ = map (+1) $ myEnum 0 1
{-# NOINLINE incInt #-}
myEnum :: a -> Integer -> [Integer]
myEnum _ n =  enumFrom n
{-# NOINLINE myEnum #-}
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (incInt 0 !!  9999999)
  print (incInt 0 !!  9999999)
  print (incInt 0 !!  9999999)
```

Any comments will be appreciated deeply. Thanks.

Comment: Usually, CAFs are _desired_, so, yes, it makes sense if GHC sometimes optimises them in. Avoiding them only makes sense in some memory-intensive applications. Have you tried this with something more RAM-heavy?

Comment: Oh, then is there any idiomatic ways to prevent CAFs? Mr. Don Stewart's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090932/how-to-make-a-caf-not-a-caf-in-haskell) and Mr. Chris Allen's book (http://haskellbook.com/) suggests making CAFs to function with dummy argument is THAT way. But the result with current (v7.10) GHC shows that the method does not work with `-O2`. My context is in 'studying' CAFs of Haskell.

Comment: Have you tried https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-dup?